# Security rights when running ASP scripts online

Tags: python, windows, iis, dll, asp-classic

I have written a python class which interacts with a third party sales db via a c dll.

I now plan to use PythonScript from my ASP script to use this python class. This ASP Script is part of my website. I have used PythonScript a little in the past as an alternative to VBScript.

In terms of security rights, will clients to my website be able to use the python class? I remember once before that I couldn't allow clients to schedule windows tasks for security reasons.

How do I safely setup the security rights?

Answer (score 3):

An web application is always letting users run code on the server, usually generating some HTML from data. That process is very locked down, and require no rights on the server. Whether that code is ASP and/or Python isn't really an issue, except that you will be using C code which is :

- Less tested
- prone to buffer overflow

This answer would also apply if you were using a custom built COM object.

Aside from the possible technical difficulties (like getting the `PYTHONPATH` right), you must **look at [Trust boundaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_boundary)**. In short, you must *do some work* on the data sent to you from the client before it becomes trustworthy. Only then can you send it on its way to your assets (your data).

What is that work exactly depends on your application, but it will probably be along these lines :

1. Authenticate the user
2. Validate the input
3. Use safe API and coding practices

The hard work is often at stage 2. Your scheduling application could have just schedule specific low impact task to run only once, instead of blindly scheduling a task submitted by the user, for example.

Same goes for your Python script application. But you should consider stage 3 also. C code does not have built-in safeguards and as such it is prone to overflow attacks.

To make it more clear, identify your trust boundaries on an high level diagram of your application. Here is an attemp at one :

[image: Hypothetical trust boundaries]

Each part of your application has a role, and you cannot cross a trust boundary without some form of validation.

For example :

1. Authenticate the user, preferably using a built-in mechanism so you benefit from robust code
2. Your Python script code validates the input. The [OWASP input validation cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet) is a good start, although the [Python ESAPI library](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Python_Readme) is still in beta. Again, this is the hard part.
3. (If possible) review your DLL code and replace all string manipulation routines with their safe counterparts. This can be an undertaking bigger than your original projet though.

The sad note is that the infrastructure will not help you. Even if this was an intranet application, with the users well known in advance, it would mostly help with the authentiation stage only.

Finally, remember that old school security measure still apply :

- Network security (firewalls, reverse proxy, etc.)
- Run only the services you need
- Apply patches and monitor logs
- Isolate your application in a worker process with very little privileges (like LOCAL SERVICE)
- Use a low priviledge account for database access

Answer (score 0):

I did not have to setup Python on IIS but I Found on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494)

> Verify that application mapping for .py files is set up. To do this, perform the following steps:
>
> - In the ISM, under Internet Information Server, right-click the computer name, and then >click Properties.
>
>   - From the Master Properties drop-down list, click WWW Service and then click Edit.
>   - Click the Home Directory tab, and then click Configuration.
>   - To add the application mapping, click Add, and then create a new mapping by using the following information (substituting the correct path on your computer):
>
>     1. Executable: "C:\Python20\python.exe %s %s" (The two "%s" after the executable are required for console-based script interpreters but would not be required for an Internet Server API [ISAPI]-based script interpreter).
>     2. Extension: .py
>     3. Script engine: selected.
>     4. Check that File Exists: selected (for security) Click OK.

...

> Verify that the file and directory permissions are set correctly in
>   the computer's access control list (ACL). For anonymous access, the
>   IUSR_[computername] and IWAM_[computername] user accounts must have at
>   least "read" permission (RX). When using other types of password
>   authentication, the permissions required may vary.